# Using Test Tubes with Water in Them as a Method to Measure Metabolism Ratios

Tags: experimental-physics

If one were to set up an experiment such that one holds a test tube for a certain period of time with thermometer in it and then another person holds a different test tube for a period of time with a thermometer in it, can we use the change in temperature change in each thermometer respectively as a method to figure out which person has a higher metabolism?

The controlled variables would include:
- Room temperature
- Starting temperature of water
- The mass of the 2 subjects
- The area of contact between the subjects and the test

If I am not mistaking myself, a part of metabolism can be seen as how fast we burn calories. Hence, with this experiment, wouldn't the person with the higher metabolism have a higher heat rise in the water in the test tube they are holding?

Comment: Apart from a lots of other variables....

Comment: Could you please provide more insight on what these other variables would be?